# How should I set up the python packages for this

Tags: python

I am creating a tool I plan to put on Github. It is very general however I want to also include some examples of its usage. As such I have set up the following folder structure.

This tool is for python 3.

```
repository/
   commonTool.py
   commonTool2.py
   specificUsage/
     runTheSpecificUsage.py
     helpRunTheSpecificUsage.py
```

Now both of the scripts in the `specificUsage/` folder will import the methods in commonTool.py and commonTool2.py.

My issue is ideally the user would be able to go

```
python repository/specificUsage/runTheSpecificUsage.py
```

However I cant get this to work. It never is able to import the functions that are in the folder above it. I have tried a variety of various posts on how to import a file from a super folder with no luck.

How should I be setting up these folders? Should I have one **init**.py or two? Where?

Comment: What import statements do you use in `runTheSpecificUsage.py` to load the methods in `commonTool.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `setup.py` at the top level along with `commonTool.py` and `commonTool2.py`. Inside your setup.py, put the following line:

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(packages=setuptools.find_packages())
```

Then put an `__init__.py` in the same level, as well as in `specificUsage/`. You should be able to import from `specificUsage` like this:

```
import commonTool
```

After setting up your files, from the top level run:

```
pip install -e .
```

You may also want to consider that Python has strong naming conventions for modules and packages and frowns upon camelcase in general. You can read more [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id40) if you like.

Comment: Should there be anything inside of the init.py files?

Comment: They can be empty, and in fact I am not sure you need the one inside `specificUsage` but it shouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: I am getting no such luck. Is there something that differentiates a file from a module?

Comment: When I run the setup.py it asks for more arguments and running the script still has the same issue

Comment: You do not need to run the setup.py file. What directory do you run the script from? What do your imports in the script look like? What is the error?

Comment: The imports in `specificUsage/runTheSpecificUsage.py` are just `import commonTool` and I run the script `specificUsage/runTheSpecificUsage.py` from either the repository/ folder or outside of it.

Comment: And the error is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commonTool'`

Comment: From the top directory where the `setup.py` file is, try running `pip install -e .` then re running your script.